# How does a classmethod object work?

Tags: python, metaclass, class-method

I'm having trouble to understand how a classmethod object works in Python, especially in the context of metaclasses and in `__new__`. In my special case I would like to get the name of a classmethod member, when I iterate through the `members` that were given to `__new__`.

For normal methods the name is simply stored in a `__name__` attribute, but for a classmethod there is apparently no such attribute. I don't even see how the classmethod is invoked, as there is no `__call__` attribute either.

Can someone explain to me how a classmethod works or point me to some documentation? Googling led me nowhere. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have insight about the "missing" `__name__`, but to be sure the classmethods have a `__call__` wrapper.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A `classmethod` object is a descriptor. You need to understand how descriptors work.

In a nutshell, a descriptor is an object which has a method `__get__`, which takes three arguments: `self`, an `instance`, and an `instance type`.

During normal attribute lookup, if a looked-up object `A` has a method `__get__`, that method gets called and what it returns is substituted in place for the object `A`.  This is how functions (which are also descriptors) become bound methods when you call a method on an object.

```
class Foo(object):
     def bar(self, arg1, arg2):
         print arg1, arg2

foo = Foo()
# this:
foo.bar(1,2)  # prints '1 2'
# does about the same thing as this:
Foo.__dict__['bar'].__get__(foo, type(foo))(1,2)  # prints '1 2'
```

A `classmethod` object works the same way.  When it gets looked up, its `__get__` method gets called.  The `__get__` of a classmethod discards the argument corresponding to the `instance` (if there was one) and only passes along the `instance_type` when it calls `__get__` on the wrapped function.

A illustrative doodle:

```
In [14]: def foo(cls):
   ....:     print cls
   ....:     
In [15]: classmethod(foo)
Out[15]: <classmethod object at 0x756e50>
In [16]: cm = classmethod(foo)
In [17]: cm.__get__(None, dict)
Out[17]: <bound method type.foo of <type 'dict'>>
In [18]: cm.__get__(None, dict)()
<type 'dict'>
In [19]: cm.__get__({}, dict)
Out[19]: <bound method type.foo of <type 'dict'>>
In [20]: cm.__get__({}, dict)()
<type 'dict'>
In [21]: cm.__get__("Some bogus unused string", dict)()
<type 'dict'>
```

More info on descriptors can be found here (among other places):
http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm

For the specific task of getting the name of the function wrapped by a `classmethod`:

```
In [29]: cm.__get__(None, dict).im_func.__name__
Out[29]: 'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! I feel it bit stupid now since in principle I knew about descriptors. But I was to confused to see that a classmethod is wrapped in a non-callable descriptor :-)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to stress how much I appreciate your very detailed answer, this is just great.

Comment: That descriptor link is gone 404.

Comment: `.im_func` is now `__func__` in python 3. [source: 2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-methodattrs)