# Is there any way to create a Python class method that does NOT pollute the attribute namespace of its instances?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I want to provide a method that can be used on a Python 2.7 class object, but does not pollute the attribute namespace of its instances. Is there any way to do this?

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   @classmethod
...   def ugh(cls):
...     return 33
...
>>> Foo.ugh()
33
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.ugh()
33
```

Comment: Technically, `ugh` is *not* in the namespace of the instance (`foo.__dict__`); it is simply accessible via the instance due to Python's lookup algorithm.

Comment: so this is baked into Python? (http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm seems to confirm that:  `For instance, a.x has a lookup chain starting with a.__dict__['x'], then type(a).__dict__['x'], and continuing through the base classes of type(a) excluding metaclasses`) I want to create some special magic stuff available on the class object but I don't want my colleagues who are using my class to accidentally call it from an instance because they are curious. It would be nice if there were a way to inhibit visibility.

Comment: Another power feature is `__dir__` to control introspection.

Comment: ["We're all consenting adults here"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)

Comment: @StephenRauch sure; I don't want to prevent someone who knows what they're doing, but I do want to limit accidental errors. In my case I have colleagues who are Python beginners, and Murphy's law says they will find a way to trip over any possible trip hazard. (and whenever I assume otherwise, it has caused problems that I have to fix.)

Comment: In what context is it actually an error to invoke a class method via an instance, though?

Comment: I've learned a heap in this question.

Comment: @chepner -- it's normally not an error to invoke a class method, but if I have a class method that creates a new subclass of the original class... well, that's not something that's appropriate for the instance callers to use, unless they really want to via `foo.__class__.powerfulMethod()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could subclass the classmethod descriptor:

```
class classonly(classmethod):
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj: raise AttributeError
        return super(classonly, self).__get__(obj, type)
```

This is how it would behave:

```
class C(object):
    @classonly
    def foo(cls):
        return 42
>>> C.foo()
42
>>> c=C()
>>> c.foo()
AttributeError
```

This desugars to the descriptor call (rather, it is invoked by the default implementation of `__getattribute__`):

```
>>> C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(None, C)
<bound method C.foo of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> C.__dict__['foo'].__get__(c, type(c))
AttributeError
```

Required reading: [Data Model — Implementing Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: my brain is fuming... could you elaborate? On the surface this seems to be something simple, but I guess I don't understand what `@classmethod` actually does under the hood.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it and this doesn't seem to work properly in Python 2.7

Comment: Aha, it's the super call.

Comment: A metaclass can override many things about the class's definition and object creation, and can have complicated side effects with inheritance. A descriptor is a type of object that overrides getattr and setattr, and can't have any side effects on the rest of the class. Near as I can tell, outside of the ABCMeta hierarchy, the stdlib (of py3) only uses two metaclasses (one in enum and one in ctypes), but uses standard @classmethod decorators and custom descriptors generously. I'd follow their lead.

Comment: cool, thanks! I tweaked it a bit to add a useful error message to `AttributeError`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677468/how-does-a-classmethod-object-work which uses `__get__(obj, type).im_func.__name__`

Answer (score 4):

`ugh` is not in the namespace:

```
>>> foo.__dict__
{}
```

but the rules for attribute lookup fall back to the type of the instance for missing names. You can override `Foo.__getattribute__` to prevent this.

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def ugh(cls):
        return 33

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'ugh':
            raise AttributeError("Access to class method 'ugh' block from instance")
        return super(Foo,self).__getattribute__(name)
```

This produces:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.ugh()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp.py", line 8, in __getattribute__
    raise AttributeError("Access to class method 'ugh' block from instance")
AttributeError: Access to class method 'ugh' block from instance
>>> Foo.ugh()
33
```

You must use `__getattribute__`, which is called unconditionally on any attribute access, rather than `__getattr__`, which is only called after the normal lookup (which includes checking the type's namespace) fails.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create the method in the metaclass.

```
class FooMeta(type):
    # No @classmethod here
    def ugh(cls):
        return 33

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta

Foo.ugh()  # returns 33
Foo().ugh()  # AttributeError
```

Note that metaclasses are a power feature, and their use is discouraged if unnecessary.  In particular, multiple inheritance requires special care if the parent classes have different metaclasses.

Comment: What is the cost of using metaclasses? This seems to be exactly the feature I'm looking for, and as long as I can keep their functionality simple, it would be something I would like to utilize. I am going to be making potentially thousands of instance objects -- if I use metaclasses, do they cost significant extra memory?

Comment: @JasonS: The main problem is that metaclasses are very powerful and can be used to do a lot of strange things with your classes (for instance, you can override special methods like `__add__` to make `Foo + Foo` a meaningful expression).  Many of these will reduce the readability of your code.

Comment: If you use them to override the very meaning of addition or such simple operations it will get confusing but other than that they are just another tool

Comment: Metaclasses do not necessarily play well with each other. The metaclass for `A` that inherits from `B` must be "compatible" with the metaclass of `B`; in practice, it somewhat limits where and when you want to use a metaclass.

Answer (score 2):

Python has [quasi-private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) that use name-munging to reduce accidental access. Methods and object variables of the form `__name` are converted to `_ClassName__name`. Python automatically changes the name when compiling methods on the class but doesn't change the name for subclasses.

I can use the private method in a class

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __private(self):
...         print('boo')
...     def hello(self):
...         self.__private()
... 
>>> 
>>> A().hello()
boo
```

But not outside the class

```
>>> A().__private()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__private'
>>>
```

Or in subclasses

```
>>> class B(A):
...     def hello2(self):
...         self.__private()
... 
>>> 
>>> B().hello()
boo
>>> B().hello2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in hello2
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute '_B__private'
```