# Why does Python 2.7 namedtuple implement __dict__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

The `namedtuple` implementation in Python 2.7 implements `__dict__`. I'm confused what this is doing; why do we need to make a special `__dict__` if there are already properties defined?

```
C:\tmp> python
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import collections
>>> x = collections.namedtuple('foo','bar baz', verbose=True)
class foo(tuple):
    'foo(bar, baz)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('bar', 'baz')

    def __new__(_cls, bar, baz):
        'Create new instance of foo(bar, baz)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (bar, baz))

    @classmethod
    def _make(cls, iterable, new=tuple.__new__, len=len):
        'Make a new foo object from a sequence or iterable'
        result = new(cls, iterable)
        if len(result) != 2:
            raise TypeError('Expected 2 arguments, got %d' % len(result))
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        'Return a nicely formatted representation string'
        return 'foo(bar=%r, baz=%r)' % self

    def _asdict(self):
        'Return a new OrderedDict which maps field names to their values'
        return OrderedDict(zip(self._fields, self))

    def _replace(_self, **kwds):
        'Return a new foo object replacing specified fields with new values'
        result = _self._make(map(kwds.pop, ('bar', 'baz'), _self))
        if kwds:
            raise ValueError('Got unexpected field names: %r' % kwds.keys())
        return result

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        'Return self as a plain tuple.  Used by copy and pickle.'
        return tuple(self)

    __dict__ = _property(_asdict)

    def __getstate__(self):
        'Exclude the OrderedDict from pickling'
        pass

    bar = _property(_itemgetter(0), doc='Alias for field number 0')

    baz = _property(_itemgetter(1), doc='Alias for field number 1')
```

Comment: Because it has `__slots__`; it wouldn't have a `__dict__` if it didn't explicitly define one.

Comment: why does it need a `__dict__`? (what feature consumes it?)

Comment: The use of ``__dict__`` was a mistake.  The goal was to make ``vars(nt)`` work, but it had unexpected side-effects on pickling and was completely unworkable in Python 3.  As a result, it was removed entirely from later versions of Python 3.  Stick with an ``_asdict`` method and you will be happy :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just thought it would be convenient. Turns out it was [more hassle than it was worth](http://bugs.python.org/issue18015), causing issues with pickling and with subclasses, and it was conceptually confusing anyway. More recent Python versions don't have it any more.

Comment: so if I'm doing something similar to `namedtuple`, can I just skip the `__dict__` assignment? If I do, what feature would I miss?

Comment: @JasonS: You can skip it. It never provided enough benefit to justify the confusion. The obvious thing you'll be missing is that `yourobject.__dict__` will raise an AttributeError, but `yourobject._asdict()` is a better way to get that functionality.

Comment: does that apply to the `__getstate__` method also?

Comment: @JasonS: You can leave that out too. It might be worth looking at the Python 3.6 namedtuple code, which is mostly compatible with Python 2.

Comment: If you want to know about the gory details of why `__dict__` appeared and disappeared, it was a muddle about getting `vars` to work on namedtuple instances.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26180604/674039) for more info.