# Register class method at program exit using chain of decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators, class-method, atexit

I have a class, one of its attributes is a class method that I want to run at program exit. This immediate idea:

```
import atexit

class Foo:
    @atexit.register
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass
```

raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "test.py", line 5, in Foo
    @classmethod
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Another immediate idea (notice the changed evaluation order of decorators):

```
import atexit

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    @atexit.register
    def foo(cls):
        pass
```

raises the following exception:

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
```

I am quite new to the concept of decorators.

- Is there any simple way how to fix this code while still use the chain of decorators?
- If not, what would you recommend as an alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should read the answer for [How does a classmethod object work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677468/how-does-a-classmethod-object-work)

But it would be interesting to see the output of the following code:

```
def mydeco(func):
    print(repr(func))
    return func

class Foo:
    @mydeco
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass

print(repr(Foo.foo))
```

If you run this, you will see

```
<classmethod object at 0x6ffffd1dc18>
<bound method Foo.foo of <class '__main__.Foo'>>
```

So the first line is from the `mydeco()` decorator and the second line is from the `print()` statement at the bottom. You see that they are different. The reason they are different is because `classmethod` is not like the function decorator you expect. It does not give you back a function, but a `classmethod` object, and it is not callable. However, at the same time, the class `Foo` that encloses it remember that in `Foo.__dict__` and when you recall the decorated class method, it give you back a callable method.

Just because the `classmethod` object is not callable. You cannot wrap it with `atexit.register`. Similar case for `staticmethod`.

So now you should realize, to register that into `atexit`, you can do it **outside the class**, like this:

```
import atexit

class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        pass

atexit.register(Foo.foo)
```

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained. The classmethod object is a bit like dark magic to me, but at least I finally understand the "argument is not callable" exception. I did not know that decorators can return objects.

Answer (score -1):

Moreover, you can also use staticmethod -

import atexit

class Foo:
@staticmethod
@atexit.register
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
pass