# Applying class decorator to staticmethod: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods, class-method

I am trying to apply a class decorator to each of its methods. But `staticmethod` and `classmethod` are not working for me. I got this:

```py
import functools
import re


def decor(cls):
    def decorator(f):

        if isinstance(f, type):
            for attr in f.__dict__:
                if callable(getattr(f, attr)) and not re.match(r"__\w*__", attr):
                    setattr(f, attr, decorator(getattr(f, attr)))
            return f

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator(cls)


@decor
class MyClass:

    def printer1(self, string):
        print(string)

    @classmethod
    def printer2(cls, string):
        print(string)

    @staticmethod
    def printer3(string):
        print(string)


MyClass().printer1("foo")  # this works
MyClass().printer2("foo")  # this does not work
MyClass.printer2("foo")    # this works
MyClass().printer3("foo")  # this does not work
MyClass.printer3("foo")    # this works

# the error is the following:
TypeError: printer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Basically every time I instantiate the class, I get the error when calling a `staticmethod` and a `classmethod`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to understand the working principle of `staticmethod` and `classmethod`. This is a link about the [working principle of classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677468/how-does-a-classmethod-object-work). The working principle of the `staticmethod` is similar to that of the `classmethod`. The difference is that when accessing the `staticmethod`, the class will not be bound to the function, but simply return the function.

---

There are two problems:

1. The decorator also wraps the class and returns a function instead of a class, which prevents `staticmethod` and `classmethod` from working properly.
2. For `staticmethod` and `classmethod`, `getattr` will get the result returned after the descriptor triggers the `__get__` method, not necessarily the function itself. And here you only use `wrapper` to wrap, and do not restore them to the corresponding special methods.

Here is a working example:

```
def decorator(cls_or_func):
    if isinstance(cls_or_func, type):
        cls = cls_or_func
        for name, attr in cls.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr, (staticmethod, classmethod)):
                setattr(cls, name, type(attr)(decorator(attr.__func__)))
            elif callable(attr) and not re.match(r"__\w*__", name):
                setattr(cls, name, decorator(attr))
        return cls

    func = cls_or_func

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```