# Bound & Unbound Method Object

Tags: python, class, methods, bounds, unbound

Below are the references of two different method objects "display_info" & "get_num". Why is it that "display_info" is unbound object whereas "get_num" is bound object despite both being referred from the same class object "Rectangle"?

```
class Rectangle:
    num = 0

    def display_info():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def get_num(cls):
        pass

print(Rectangle.display_info)
print(Rectangle.get_num)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<function Rectangle.display_info at 0x7f02d97405e0>
<bound method Rectangle.get_num of <class '__main__.Rectangle'>>
```

Comment: Are you interested in what the difference between function objects and bound-method objects is in general, or are you specifically asking why `classmethod` creates a bound-method object? Are you familiar with [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)?

Comment: Site note: `display_info` is missing a `self` parameter. `Rectanger().display_info()` raises an error.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#class-methods) is the python equivalent code of `classmethod`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a classmethod object work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677468/how-does-a-classmethod-object-work)